# Chrome source maps debugging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, source-maps, grunt-contrib-uglify

I encounter problems when debugging using the source maps in the Chrome browser.
I generating source maps with grunt-contrib-uglify. On the development environment everything works as it should, but production did not. 
Source map exists, but in Chrome in the "Sources" tab map did not load. Everything works in Firefox, but do not in Chrome.
Chrome version - 45.0.2454.101

Thanks for any help.